# Compiling a new filesystem into the Linux Kernel

Tags: linux, filesystems, kernel

I'm working on building a new filesystem as a prototype on Debian because existing file systems do not meet certain requirements that I have. It's meant to be a prototype to evaluate certain requirements we have.

To do this, I first thought of taking an example [file system such as testfs from GitHub](https://github.com/mkatiyar/testfs) to attempt to compile it. I'm on step (e) in the [read me](https://github.com/mkatiyar/testfs/blob/master/README) but I'm not sure how exactly to compile the Linux.

---

**Steps followed so far:**

I'm trying to make using the [provided MakeFile](https://github.com/mkatiyar/testfs/blob/master/Makefile) for the project but this is the error I get.

```
make -C /home/username/Workspace/testfs M=`pwd` modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/username/Workspace/testfs'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `modules'. Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/username/Workspace/testfs'
make: *** [testfs] Error 2
```

From what I understand, it needs the kernel source (which is in my `/usr/src`).

```
debian:testfs karun$l /usr/src/
total 74M
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4.0K Jan  8 18:34 linux-headers-3.2.0-4-686-pae
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4.0K Jan  8 18:34 linux-headers-3.2.0-4-common
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   23 Jun 24  2012 linux-kbuild-3.2 -> ../lib/linux-kbuild-3.2
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 122K Sep 18 20:20 linux-patch-3.2-rt.patch.bz2
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   25 Jan 10 20:21 linux-source -> /usr/src/linux-source-3.2
drwxr-xr-x 22 root root 4.0K Sep 18 20:20 linux-source-3.2
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  74M Sep 18 20:22 linux-source-3.2.tar.bz2
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   49 Jan  8 14:29 vboxguest-4.3.6 -> /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.6/src/vboxguest-4.3.6
```

Alterantive attempt was to try to compile the Kernel with the FS code and then "install" it.

- I got the kernel source by following the [instructions on the Debian page to compile a new kernel](http://www.debian.org/releases/wheezy/i386/ch08s06.html.en).
- I ran `make menuconfig` and went into the "File systems --->" section

---

**Question:** How do I make my module visible on `menuconfig` so as to ensure it gets compiled with the source and deployed?

My end goal is to be able to **format a drive** (HDD volume or flash drive) **to my custom file system** (let's call it CustFS, like NTFS or HFS :)) for storing data and not necessarily running the Linux OS off it. I've tried my best to come up with steps to do this but I can't find the right help.

From what I understand I need to do the following

- Write the FS code
- Compile it with the kernel source
- Deploy the new Kernel

FUSE, I believe, won't allow me to achieve what I want. I'd like to create a FS on a thumb drive (as a test) then on a HDD so as to be able to extend it to go past restrictions it currently has in terms of files per folder (one amongst a  few).

---

**Environment Details:**

- Debian 7.3 (wheezy) running off VirtualBox
- Linux Kernel  version 3.2.0-4-686-pae (Dump from `uname -r`)

---

If there are any other question you might have or require clarification, please let me know. Pointing me towards some tutorial/steps of things I need to go through will really help.
Thanks!

*Side note, I'm a programmer who's spent most of his time working on Java. I (believe) I have a decent working knowledge in C/C++ and can build skills on top, as required. This is my first time attempting to compile the kernel and I'm not sure how to add modules to it.*

Answer (score 0):

Typically one would start by implementing a file system in FUSE. This allows you the convenience of developing in userland which is much easier to work with.

You can almost certainly do anything in FUSE and the primary reason you would not use FUSE is if you are worried about performance. Both ZFS and NTFS are (or were) implemented in FUSE.

If you go the kernel route you will find your file system is much harder to debug and that the development process is much more complicated. If you don't know what the real difference is between userland and kernel space avoid trying to make a kernel module at all costs.

---

**Update**: To be clear; anything you can do as a kernel based file system you can do in FUSE. With a kernel module, you are never reading directly from a hard disk, you read from a block device, which your file system then interprets and provides a file interface on top of. In FUSE, you do the exact same thing, the only difference is that instead of your program being in Kernel space, it is in Userland.

There is absolutely no reason to develop a new file system starting from a Kernel module, FUSE is fast enough, much easier, and provides a much better framework for test and verification.

Comment: Quote from my post: "FUSE, I believe, won't allow me to achieve what I want. I'd like to create a FS on a thumb drive (as a test) then on a HDD so as to be able to extend it to go past restrictions it currently has in terms of files per folder (one amongst a few)." Any ideas how to format a thumb drive with a custom FS implementation and decide how data is stored at a block level using FUSE? I couldn't find any documentation around that.

Comment: Use the raw interfaces (such as /dev/sd) that the OS already provides. If you are looking for specific guidance I'd suggest finding an existing FUSE project close to what you are doing and then modify it and/or asking a specific question here.